# Already loaded video data is being discarded

Tags: youtube, video, cache

As you probably know, the YouTube video player caches the loaded portions of the video so one can seek to any previously-loaded part of the video *without* re-downloading it. When viewing a video and the playback stops in order for the player to buffer more of the video, I usually go back to a previous already-downloaded point (less boring than staring at the throbber).

After I click on the orange area:

[image: Going back]

the player seems to **discard** the cached file and start re-downloading the video starting at the specified point. This has been happening for quite a while, and it's bothering on my low-speed connection.

Why is this happening and is there a workaround?

<sub>I tried using the experimental HTML5 player; it showed the same issue.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug that YouTube needs to fix. As the player is Flash, there's no possible workaround for this issue. But there's a better way to watch YouTube videos from a PC video player called VLC, if you don't have VLC, search the web for download links.

Open VLC Player -> Click the `Media` tab in the menu bar -> Select `Open Network Stream` and paste the URL to the YouTube video you want to watch.

Tip #1: You can also play a playlist, just paste the URL to your playlist.

Comment: It's awesome to know VLC can play YouTube videos; quite impressive. I can't seem to get it to work just now, but I'll investigate the issue. Thank you! One more thing — is the bug documented/filed?

Comment: I don't know, but it's a common issue, so people might have already filed the report for this bug. Also, keep your Flash player updated, to get the best out of YouTube player.